# Can I run/emulate my Ionic app on my own device?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is it possible to emulate/run my ionic app on my own device (iOS) without using an Ionic view? 
If so, how can I do it? Can I do it with android too?

I'm developing on windows btw.

Comment: connect your device with usb debug enabled..`ionic run <platform>` or `ionic emulate <platform>`  http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/

Comment: if you are using android its better to use `phonegap` application available in playstore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you need develop for iOS then you need to do it in iMac. Read the link below:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/cli/emulate/